# What is do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_collaterals' ); use for in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I am working with a woocommerce theme and I am updating the cart.php file. But I wonder `do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_collaterals' );`  why this is use for. I am trying to comment on it but nothing seems changed on my cart page.
What is the role of this line in woocommerce?

Comment: A [simple search on StackOverFlow typing `woocommerce_before_cart_collaterals`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_before_cart_collaterals) gives you all related threads that are using tis hook and allow you to understand what you can do with it…

Answer (score 2):

As the name of the hook implies, it can be used to display a message/HTML/etc.. before the cart collaterals.

Example:

```php
function action_woocommerce_before_cart_collaterals() {
    echo '<h2>MY MESSAGE</h2>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_collaterals', 'action_woocommerce_before_cart_collaterals', 10, 0 );
```

---

The `cart-collaterals` div contains:

- `cart_totals` div from the `cart/cart-totals.php` template file
- When cross sells are set for products, they will be displayed in the `cross-sells` div from the `cart/cross-sells.php` template file